# jquery ajax always return error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, servlets

it always returns error as:

```
error[object Object]
```

the java code didn't print "test" to console, so i think the java method never get called. but i don't see anything wrong with my js code.
any help would be heavily appreciated!

javascript

```
var server = '/getPeriodDropdown.htm';
var dataString = 'selected='+$(this).find('option:selected').val();
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : server,
    data : dataString,
    success : function(data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error : function(error) {
        alert("error" + error);
    }
});
```

java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPeriodDropdown.htm")
public String getPeriodTime(@ModelAttribute("rptType") ReportBo rt,Model model, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws APSException, IOException {
    String selected = request.getParameter("selected");
    System.out.println("selected: " + selected);
    return "reports";
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would alert/log the error text. it's the third parameter. The statusText from the second parameter might help too.

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd parameter are error and Not Found.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you very much. I found the reason. the url /getPeriodDropdown.htm should be getPeriodDropdown.htm

Comment: For future reference, use `console.log()` such as in `console.log(data);` and then open up the console window so that you don't get those useless `[object][object]` messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the the problem in your url. It must be

```
var server = 'getPeriodDropdown.htm';
```